# Calculate Average Time Difference in Excel when data is

Tags: excel

[image]

I need the Average difference from Time assigned minus Time created calculated. I was not able to change the format of this data in excel for some reason. it is in the general format.

Comment: What have you tried, and what results did you get. In general, if you are unable to change the format of the timestamp data in Excel, then they are text strings and not real dates.  So that may be your first job.  How did the data get into Excel?

Answer (score 0):

Formula used to extract date, month and year

```
=(DATE(MID(E2,8,5),MONTH(LEFT(E2,5)),MID(SUBSTITUTE(E2,",",""),4,3))+TIMEVALUE(RIGHT(E2,8)))-(DATE(MID(D2,8,5),MONTH(LEFT(D2,5)),MID(SUBSTITUTE(D2,",",""),4,3))+TIMEVALUE(RIGHT(D2,8)))
```

Formula to calculate average

```
=AVERAGE(F2:F9)
```

[image: Sample data and result]

Change the column F format to hh:mm